# ObservableCollection updating elements content : not getting notifications

Tags: c#, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

i've bound my datagrid to an observable collection of my ViewModel element, and then i linked it to a NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler event:

```
obsListOfClients = new ObservableCollection<ClientVM>();
foreach (var c in contexte.listOfClients)
{
    ClientVM cvm = new ClientVM(c);
    obsListOfClients.Add(cvm);
}
obsListOfClients.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(collectionOfClientssChanged);
```

i'm editing my datagrid in my vue , i want to be able to add/remove, update content and get notified when each of these operation is done : i've so created this function :

```
 void collectionOfClientssChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     switch (e.Action)
     {
         case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
         //Ajouter dans la base de données :
             for(int i = 0; i<e.NewItems.Count;i++)
             {
                 ClientVM item = e.NewItems[i] as ClientVM;
                 contexte.ListOfClientsToAdd.Add(item.Client);
             }
             break;

         case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
             for(int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
             {
                 ClientVM item = e.OldItems[i] as ClientVM;
                 contexte.ListOfClientsToRemove.Add(item.Client);
             }
             break;

         case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
             for(int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
             {
                 ClientVM item = e.OldItems[i] as ClientVM;
                 contexte.ListOfClientsToUpdate.Add(item.Client);
             }
             break;
     }
}
```

Then i use my three lists ( ListOfClientsToUpdate, ListOfClientsToRemove, ListOfClientsToAdd) to keep a trace of my changes and be able to push all modifications once in database.

The problem is that when i add or remove rows in my datagrid , i get the notification and the lists are filled with elements, but when i update the content of an existing row , i don't even get an notification about the collection changing!!! so i'm not able to keep a trace of my modifications on existing elements!

Any idea ? thanks a lot :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect a change to an element in the list you need to listen to property changes on ClientVM as these don't count as changes to the list of clients.

Very roughly, you could do something like:

```
obsListOfClients = new ObservableCollection<ClientVM>();
foreach (var c in contexte.listOfClients)
{
    ClientVM cvm = new ClientVM(c);
    // NEW BIT HERE
    cvm.PropertyChanged += ClientVMChangedEventHandler;
    obsListOfClients.Add(cvm);
}
obsListOfClients.CollectionChanged += ...;

private void ClientVMChangedEventHandler(object sender,
                                         PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    contexte.ListOfClientsToUpdate.Add(((ClientVM)sender).Client);
}
```

And do the same when you add new items.  Don't forget to remove the event handler when removing items.

Answer (score 1):

Does `ClientVM` implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface? Also: You're monitoring changes to the collection itself, not for their items.

The `CollectionChanged` event isn't supposed to be called when a property of a collection item changes, but only when the collection itself changes - which is what you're experiencing.

To get notified about changes for the individual items, I suggest you subscribe to/unsubscribe from the `PropertyChanged` events of each `ClientVM` instance that's added/replaced/removed from the `ObservableCollection` in the code that you've posted above. Example for the add and remove case could be:

```
switch (e.Action)
{
    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
        for(int i = 0; i<e.NewItems.Count;i++)
        {
            ClientVM item = e.NewItems[i] as ClientVM;
            item.PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged;
            contexte.ListOfClientsToAdd.Add(item.Client);
        }
        break;

    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
        for(int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
        {
            ClientVM item = e.OldItems[i] as ClientVM;
            item.PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged;
            contexte.ListOfClientsToRemove.Add(item.Client);
        }
        break;
}
```

With `ItemPropertyChanged` being the event handler:

```
private void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle property change here
}
```

Comment: Yup , it implements it:
`code` public class ClientVM : ViewModelBase
{
  //Constructeurs:
   public ClientVM(Clients c)
        {
            Client = new Clients();
            Client = c;
            SocialIdentity = c.SocialIdentity;
            Phone = c.PhoneNumber;
            MailAddress = c.MailAddress;
  }
    //Attributs:
    private Clients client;
    public Clients Client
        {
        get { return client; }
        set
       {
            if (client != value)
             {
              client = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("Client");
          }
     }
}`code`

Answer (score 1):

That is because your collection, in fact, does **not** change. Each element in your collection is a *reference* to an object. The object changes, but the reference stays the same. Therefore, the collection does not change.

An **update** operation on an observable collection means replacing an element with a different one. That is not what happens in your case.

You will need a more complicated solution for your problem, that also registers for property change notification on the objects in the collection.